# Pointer events don't support simultaneous mouse buttons

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

While `mousedown`/`mouseup` can handel multiple mouse buttons and `pointerdown`/`pointerup` can handle multitouch, `pointerdown`/`pointerup` can not handle two or more simultaneous mouse buttons. (Tested in Chrome/Firefox on Windows)

As expected mouse events:

```
mousedown, button: 0
mousedown, button: 1
mouseup, button: 0
mouseup, button: 1
```

Unexpected with pointer events:

```
pointerdown, button: 0
// button 1 pressed, nothing
// button 0 release, nothing
pointerup, button: 1
```

Demo:

```js
window.addEventListener('pointerdown', (e) => {
  console.log('pointerdown', e.pointerId, e.pointerType, e.button)
})
window.addEventListener('pointerup', (e) => {
  console.log('pointerup', e.pointerId, e.pointerType, e.button)
})
window.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  console.log('mousedown', e.button)
})
window.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  console.log('mouseup', e.button)
})
```

```html
Click anywhere
```

Is this to be expected or a (known) bug?

*When do you need this? E.g. panning a surface with middle mouse button, while selecting with left mouse button.*

Comment: Interestingly: _" `pointerdown` [...] For mouse, it is fired when the device transitions from no buttons pressed to at least one button pressed"_ and for `mousedown` events you can use `MouseEvent.buttons` (plural) to know which ones are currently pressed